# Inequality between integrals involving terms $\sqrt{x-a}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality

(1) There is a universal constant $C$ s.t. for all $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$\displaystyle\int_0^1\frac{|x-\alpha|^{\frac{1}{2}}}{|x-\beta|^{\frac{1}{2}}}\mathrm{d}x\geqslant C\displaystyle\int_0^1|x-\beta|^{\frac{1}{2}}\mathrm{d}x.$$

The question is too difficult for me. I don't even know how to start. I hope I can get your advice. Thank you.

Comment: @ Martin R It has been revised. Please help me. Thank you

Comment: @ Martin R It hasn't been released

Comment: This looks wrong to me. For $\beta \to \infty$ (and fixed $\alpha$) the left-hand side becomes small and the right-hand side becomes large.

Comment: @Martin R well,thank you sir.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to change your title "How to prove the following question comes from my homework" which could be given to almost any question.